# Copying autofilter data to another column

Tags: vba, excel, copy, autofilter

The below code filtered the data based on column S & T. Then it writes the "Resub UW" on visible data.
Currently I am trying to copy the visible date data in column K to the visible empty data in column AO. If anyone can help me with this code.

```
`Sub ReSubmitted_UW()
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
With ActiveSheet

.Range("$A:$AN").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>"
.Range("$A:$AN").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="="


lastRow = .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastRow > 2 Then
.Range(.Range("E2"), .Range("E" & lastRow)). _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "ReSub UW"
End If
.Range("$A:$AN").AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to copy values from one column in a filtered range to another column:

```
Sub CopyOneFilteredColumnToAnother()
    ' always declare your variables! (use option explicit)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Range("$A:$AN").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>"
    ws.Range("$A:$AN").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="="

    lastRow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If lastRow > 2 Then
        ws.Range("AO2:AO" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = _
            ws.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2
    End If

    ' turn autofilters back off
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```